# Custom Login page wordpress and custom errors handle

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to develop a custom login and registration form for my wordpress site, but i have some doubts. I need to handle all the errors with javascript, so is there a way to get the errors or the success via javascript? I thought to create a function.

I've looked onto the internet but i didn't found anything